# Writing to shared preferences too slow?

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-file

I have created a service that writes some information about a widget once a user places it on home screen(the info is picked up from the confutation activity)..i also write down the number of widgets the user has set up.

Once the user removes the widget i delete that info in the shared preferences.

What i have experienced is that if user places for example 2 widgets, then removes one, then places one again, doing all those actions fast, the shared preferences file gets inconsistent values in it. Sometimes it works ok but most of the time i get stuck with wrong values in it.

I am using apply(), i've tried with commit but same thing happens.

The values i store in the shared preferences are crucial for the system to work, without it the widgets are useless since they are backed up by info from internet based on the user configuration which is written in preferences.

Is switching to a database solution more reliable or any other viable solution which will fix this "race condition"? (maybe forcing my own mechanism of synchronization, but as far as i've understood from docs, apply() is already synchronized, and the read/write should first go to RAM which should make it fast and i shouldnt be experiencing any problems like this since the user cant physically manage to delete a widget and place a new one faster then 2-3 seconds top!)

Comment: saving to shared preferences is suppose to be pretty quick, much much quicker than using a database

Comment: is the key that you are putting in your sharedpreference file the same between widgets? if so, it should be dynamic or have an id concatenated to the key

Comment: It is dynamic, so there is no duplicates, they key-value pars are all unique.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **synchronized** keyword in working with the *SharedPreferences* itself. For example, here is a method that could be used when setting an application String in the SharedPreferences of an Android app:

```
public synchronized static void setAppString(Context context, String pref,
                                             String val) {
    SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(
            APP_PREFS_UNIQUE_ID, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putString(pref, val);
    editor.commit();
}
```

For few/simple key-value pairs, you might not need the overhead of a database paradigm.

Comment: Didnt help, i imposed some synchronization of my own to fix things to prevent this from happening.